# How can I access my node data in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a node web server that gets data from a nedb database. I want to pass this data to some ejs code on my page but node dies and tells me that there is no data in the JSON object I'm passing. Here is the server code:

```
"use strict";

const DATA_HANDLER = require('./node/DataHandler');

class app {
     constructor() {
          this.ejsData = null;
          this.loadServer();
     }

     loadServer() {
          const HTTP = require('http'),
               EJS = require('ejs'),
               PORT = 1337,
               SERVER = HTTP.createServer((req, res) => {
                    let httpHandler = (err, str, contentType) => {
                         if (err) {
                              res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                              res.end('An error has occurred: ' + err.message);
                         } else if (contentType.indexOf('image') >= 0) {
                              res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                              res.end(str, 'binary');
                         } else {
                              res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                              res.end(EJS.render(str, {
                                   data: this.ejsData,
                                   filename: 'index.ejs'
                              }));
                         }
                    };

                    if (req.method == 'POST') {
                         if (req.headers['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
                              this.loadData(req, res, 0);
                         } else if (req.headers['x-requested-load'] === 'XMLHttpRequest1') {
                              this.loadData(req, res, 1);
                         } else {
                              console.log("[405] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
                              res.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                              res.end('<html><head><title>405 - Method not supported</title></head><body><h1>Method not supported.</h1></body></html>');
                         }
                    } else if (req.url.indexOf('/javascripts/') >= 0) {
                         this.render(req.url.slice(1), 'application/ecmascript', httpHandler, 'utf-8');
                    } else if (req.url.indexOf('/css/') >= 0) {
                         this.render(req.url.slice(1), 'text/css', httpHandler, 'utf-8');
                    } else if (req.url.indexOf('/images/') >= 0) {
                         this.render(req.url.slice(1), 'image/jpeg', httpHandler, 'binary');
                    } else {
                         this.render('public/views/index.ejs', 'text/html', httpHandler, 'utf-8');
                    }
               }).listen(PORT, _ => console.log('-= Work Order Server Listening at http://127.0.0.1:' + PORT + ' =-'));
     }

     render(path, contentType, callback, encoding) {
          const FS = require('fs');
        FS.readFile(__dirname + '/' + path, encoding ? encoding : 'utf-8', (err, str) => { // ternary
            callback(err, str, contentType);
        });
     }

     loadData(req, res, whichAjax) {
          if (whichAjax === 1) {
               const FORMIDABLE = require('formidable');
               let formData = {};
               new FORMIDABLE.IncomingForm().parse(req).on('field', (field, name) => {
                    formData[field] = name;
               }).on('error', (err) => {
                    next(err);
               }).on('end', () => {
                    new DATA_HANDLER().queryData(formData);
               });
          }
          new DATA_HANDLER().loadData((docs) => {
               let jsonDocs = JSON.stringify(docs);
               res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
               res.end(jsonDocs);
               this.setEjsData(docs);
          });
     }

     setEjsData(docs) {
          this.ejsData = docs;
     }
}

module.exports = app;
```

Here is my ejs page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <table>
            <% if (data) { %>
                <% for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= data.building %></td>
                        <td><%= data.roomNumber %></td>
                        <td><%= data.problemDesc %></td>
                        <td><%= data.assigned %></td>
                        <td><%= data.status %></td>
                    </tr>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error is that data.length is null. I added the if (data) block to stop the error. I am not using any frameworks (Express or Koa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the lines from question above that solved the issue:

app.js

```
else if (contentType.indexOf('html') >= 0) {
     res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
     res.end(EJS.render(str, {
          data: this.ejsData,
          filename: 'index.ejs' }));
 }
```

ejs file:

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
     <tr>
          <td><%= data[i].date %></td>
          <td><%= data[i].building %></td>
          <td><%= data[i].roomNumber %></td>
          <td><%= data[i].problemDesc %></td>
          <td><%= data[i].assigned %></td>
          <td><%= data[i].status %></td>
     </tr>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by using `ejsData` instead of `data` in your ejs template

Comment: This is partially correct. Please see my solution below.